# connect/authenticate with google using grails oauth plugin

Tags: grails, oauth, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am trying to connect with Google using the grails oauth plugin. Following is my code

*Config.groovy*

```
oauth {
  providers {
    google {
        api = org.scribe.builder.api.GoogleApi
        key = 'XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        secret = 'XXXXXXX'

        scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
        callback = "${grails.serverURL}/oauth/google/callback"
        successUri = "${grails.serverURL}/oauthCallBack/google"
    }
  }
}

grails.google.api.url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
```

*OauthCallBackController.groovy*

```
class OauthCallBackController {

  def oauthService

  def google() {
    Token googleAccessToken = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('google')]
    def googleResource = oauthService.getGoogleResource(googleAccessToken, grailsApplication.config.grails.google.api.url)
    def googleResponse = JSON.parse(googleResource?.getBody())

    log.info "googleAccessToken = ${googleAccessToken}"
    log.info "googleResponse = ${googleResponse}"
    log.info "accesstoken = ${googleAccessToken.token}"

    def googleResourceDetailed = oauthService.getGoogleResource(googleAccessToken, "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=${googleAccessToken.token}")
    def googleResponseDetailed = JSON.parse(googleResourceDetailed?.getBody())

    log.info "googleResourceDetailed = ${googleResourceDetailed}"
    log.info "googleResponseDetailed = ${googleResponseDetailed}"

    render params
  }
}
```

When I trying to connect, google ask me to allow the application to access my credentials. After allowing my call back action executed(oauthCallBack/google) but I am not getting the data of my account.

Following is my output in my logs

```
INFO  example.OauthCallBackController  - googleAccessToken = Token[1/xxx , yyy]
INFO  example.OauthCallBackController  - googleResponse = [:]
INFO  example.OauthCallBackController  - accesstoken = 1/xxx
INFO  example.OauthCallBackController  - googleResourceDetailed = org.scribe.model.Response@2a088ca
INFO  example.OauthCallBackController  - googleResponseDetailed = [error:[message:Invalid Credentials, errors:[[message:Invalid Credentials, location:Authorization, reason:authError, locationType:header, domain:global]], code:401]]
```

I have no idea where I am wrong and why I am getting the error as response.

**How can I get data from google?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally..,.

After lots of google search I finally figure out my problem and successfully got data from google.

The problem is in my `grails.google.api.url` entry in my config file.

Correct value is

```
grails.google.api.url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
```

Now my code is

*Config.groovy*

```
oauth {
  providers {
    google {
      api = org.scribe.builder.api.GoogleApi
      key = 'XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'
      secret = 'XXXXXXX'

      scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
      callback = "${grails.serverURL}/oauth/google/callback"
      successUri = "${grails.serverURL}/oauthCallBack/google"
    }
  }
}

grails.google.api.url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
```

*OauthCallBackController.groovy*

```
def google() {
    Token googleAccessToken = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('google')]
    def googleResource = oauthService.getGoogleResource(googleAccessToken, grailsApplication.config.grails.google.api.url)
    def googleResponse = JSON.parse(googleResource?.getBody())

    log.info "googleAccessToken = ${googleAccessToken}"
    log.info "googleResponse = ${googleResponse}"
    log.info "accesstoken = ${googleAccessToken.token}"
    log.info "id = ${googleResponse.id}"
    log.info "name = ${googleResponse.name}"

    render params
}
```

And my log out put is

```
INFO  example.OauthCallBackController  - googleAccessToken = Token[1/xxx , yyy]
INFO  example.OauthCallBackController  - googleResponse = [id:xxxxx, locale:en, link:yyyyy, name:MKB, gender:male, family_name:B, given_name:M]
INFO  example.OauthCallBackController  - accesstoken = 1/xxx
INFO  example.OauthCallBackController  - id = xxxxx
INFO  example.OauthCallBackController  - name = MKB
```

---

<kbd>[Grails Oauth Plugin Demo](https://github.com/manishkbharti/grailsOauthPluginDemo)</kbd>